# Caliburm Micro Conductors opening other conductors

Tags: caliburn.micro, caliburn

Please suggest some resource/sample to implement following scenario, using Caliburn Micro :

Main Page -Conductor A
Main Page has two tabs - Each tab opens two conductors B and C

Conductor B has two screens -Screen 1 and Screen 2

Conductor C has two screens -Screen 3 and Screen 4

Screens 1,2,3,4 publishes events using EventAggergator to Conductor A based on which Conductor A decides to enable/disable the two tabs (activate/deactivate Conductors B and C)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any samples that have that exact arrangement but I can't see anything immediately wrong with what you've described.

Do you have any specific problems implementing the above?